# Interpolation in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprite, interpolation

How can I use interpolation in libgdx ?

Say if I have sprite and I want to manipulate its size as it begins at 0,0
and end at its full size

I have this :

```
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
Sprite star = new Sprite(new Texture("star.png"));

public void render(float delta) {
     batch.begin();
     batch.draw(star, 100, 100, star.getOriginX(), star.getOriginY(),
       star.getWidth(), star.getHeight(), star.getScaleX(), star.getScaleY(),
       star.getRotation());
     batch.end;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With SpriteBatch: You can use Tween engine (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) to do the job with the numbers.

With Scene2D: You can use actors and use addAction() to animate the transformation automatically. Actions are pretty cool and support many types of interpolations.